# Line Continuation on VBA, SQL statement

Tags: sql, syntax-error, vba6

I'm trying to do line continuation on vb and i getting an error, here is my code

```
sql = "Insert into RECRUITMENT values (" JobID ",'"Department"', "Employment_Level",'"Line_Manager"', '"New_vacancy_or_Replacement"', '"Recruiter"','"Position_Status"', '"Recruitment_Stage"', '"Region"', '"Minimum_Required_Qualification"' ,'"City_or_Town"',"Date_RFS_Issued"," & "Date_of_Final_RFS_Sign_or_HC_Approval","&_
"Date_Advertised","Date_of_Capture","Return_Date","Date_Shortlist_Sent_to_LineManager","Date_Put_on_Hold","Date_For_1st_Interview","Date_For_2nd_Interview","Date_For_3rd_Interview","Date_of_Assessment",'"Assessment_Type"','"Inhouse_or_Outsourced"',"Assessment_Score ","Date_Offer_Sent","Date_Offer_Accepted",'"Candidate_Selected", "&_
"Candidate_Qualification"," StartDate",'"EE_Status"','"EE_Compliant"','"Reasons_for_Deviation"','"Promotion_or_Lateral_Movement"', '"Nationality"','"Comments"')"
```

[image]

I tried to add the "&_" but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: You have one string here: `"Insert into RECRUITMENT values (" JobID` which ends at `"`, and then you just have JobID without concatenation. And same thing continues all over

Answer (score 1):

The line continuation token is defined by a SPACE followed by an UNDERSCORE, followed by a NEWLINE.

Moreover, when immediately following a literal expression, the `&` character is a *type hint* for a `Long`, and the string literal won't convert into that data type: make sure there's always a space before and after the concatenation operators.

Replace `"&_` with `" & _` and the line continuations will work... But the inner concatenations are missing, `"some string"someField","` is not legal syntax, needs to become `"some string" & someField & ","` to be valid.

Side note, with [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) (free, open-source VBE add-in) autocompletion you would only need to hit ENTER in the middle of a long string literal to automatically have it correctly split-up and line-continuated.